# What is the difference between commute and alter in Clojure?

Tags: concurrency, clojure, transactions, stm

I am trying to write very simple code which shows different results between commute and alter in Clojure. Can someone create an example for this purpose?

Simpler is better to understand the difference.

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic. It's asking for an example, but could just as well have been phrased like "What is the difference between commute and alter? Can anyone show me a function that demonstrates them behving differently?"

Comment: I agree this is a valid and not obviously duplicate question. No easy answer comes to mind because they both always produce the same answer the just do so in different amounts of time, sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `commute` is used correctly, there should be no difference in observed values of Refs, except insofar as using `commute` may help a transaction commit in a high-contention scenario where it would be difficult to do so with `alter`. Of course when this applies it is a rather significant difference in outcome…

It's easier to illustrate exactly how things differ using side effects. Here's a single-threaded example to illustrate the basic property that

- `alter` will be called exactly once per "transaction try" (possibly only once),
- `commute` will be called exactly once per "transaction try" (while `commute` will not cause them, it may be involved in retries if `alter` is used within the same `dosync` block) and then one final time to compute the committed value (so at least twice, though again, it will not cause retries on its own):

---

```
user=> (def r (ref nil))
#'user/r
user=> (dosync (alter r prn))
nil
nil
user=> (dosync (commute r prn))
nil
nil
nil
```

---

Using some `Thread/sleep`s and a handful of threads one could provoke more retries on the `alter` side while still observing two retries on the `commute` side, investigate the effect on Ref histories of using one or the other etc.